# How Can I Implement The flush Option For Watchers In Vue 2?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a data property the affects how the component's template is drawn. When the data property is updated the template gets redrawn reactively.

When the DOM updates I want to run a method that evaluates the status of a list of checkboxes and decides if the select all checkbox should be checked or not.

In Vue 3, this seems like the correct way:

```
watch: {
  // users are filtered, reset select all checkboxes
  users: {
    handler(newUsers, oldUsers) {
      this.shouldBeSelectAll();
    },
    flush: 'post'
  }
},
```

The flush option doesn't seem to be available in Vue 2. Is there a way to achieve this without using setTimeout?

Upgrading to Vue 3 isn't currently an option.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `flush: 'post'` means that your watcher is run after all changes to the dom have completed (meaning your watcher might cause another rendering cycle). If you need this with vue 2, try `Vue.nextTick()`, which will execute a callback when rendering is done:

```js
watch: {
  users(newUsers, oldUsers) {
    Vue.nextTick(() => this.shouldBeSelectAll());
  }
},
```